# Does rate of acceleration affect the amount of energy used to accelerate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Assume you start with a car at rest. Then you accelerate the car to 100 kilometers per hour. In terms of the energy needed, does it matter how fast you accelerated the car?

In other words, do you need to provide the same amount of energy to accelerate a car from 0 to 100 kilometers per hour whether you do it in 4 seconds or 20 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

> Does rate of acceleration affect the amount of energy used to
>   accelerate?

The answer is, in a *certain* sense, no.

But, really, your question as worded is ambiguous.  What does "energy used to accelerate" actually *mean*?

There is an energy associated with a change in speed which is precisely the change in kinetic energy:

$$\Delta KE = \dfrac{m}{2}(v^2_f - v^2_i)$$

Now, since it is *net* force that accelerates an object, then, if "energy used to accelerate" means "*net* force over distance to change speed from $v_i$ to $v_f$", then, in this sense, the answer to your question is **no**.

However, the *applied* force may not be the *net* force on the object as there may be, e.g., a frictional force.

So, if "energy used to accelerate" means "*applied* force over distance to change speed from $v_i$ to $v_f$", then the answer to your question is **yes**.

> In other words, do you need to provide the same amount of energy to
>   accelerate a car from 0 to 100 kilometers per hour whether you do it
>   in 4 seconds or 20 seconds?

If it's a real car, there is energy associated with simply *maintaining* a non-zero speed so, again, it depends on what you mean by "energy to accelerate a care".  Do you mean "energy above and beyond that which is required to overcome the losses" or something else?

Comment: My question was a little unclear. Let me put it a different way. Assume you have an electric car that has a battery with 25 kilowatt hours of charge. You accelerate the car from 0 to 100 kilometers per hour in 4 seconds, and measure the amount of energy used. Then you accelerate the car from 0 to 100 kilometers per hour in 20 seconds, and measure the amount of energy used. Was the energy used the same?

Comment: @user31432, for the larger current required for the larger acceleration, there will be larger IR (resistive) losses.  For the smaller acceleration, there will be larger frictional and air resistance losses over time.  So, unless these losses are zero, it's not possible to say without additional inputs.  If the losses are zero, the energy required is simply the change in KE which is the same in both cases.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there might be differences in losses depending on how fast you accelerate the car. But I find it interesting that there is no physics penalty for fast acceleration. Normally when you get something good -- like fast acceleration -- you have to pay a price for it, like requiring more energy. Here you don't pay any penalty. It takes no more energy to accelerate quickly than it does to accelerate slowly. Interesting.

Comment: In an ideal, lossless situation, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This answer ignores the effects of dissipative forces like friction and air resistance.

---

You're confusing *power* with *energy*

The total energy of the car is the sum of its kinetic and potential energies. This, of course, ignores internal energy, etc, which remain constant for the car during the time we care about it.

The energy of the car is 
\begin{equation}
E = \text{Kinetic} + \text{Potential}\\
E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + mgh
\end{equation}

Initially, the car will have 0 kinetic energy (since its velocity is zero) and some potential energy $P_1=mgh_1$

\begin{equation}
E_1 = mgh_1
\end{equation}

After it is accelerated,
\begin{equation}
E_2 = \frac{1}{2}m(100km/h)^2 + mgh_2
\end{equation}

The energy needed is:
\begin{equation}
\Delta E = E_2 - E_1 = \frac{1}{2}m(100km/hr)^2 + mg(h_2 - h_1)
\end{equation}

Notice that none of this depends on the time taken, only on the initial and final velocities and heights.

The *power supplied*, however, is the work done (or energy supplied) per unit time.

Conclusion:

Energy needed is independent of time.
Power required is greater if you do it in 4 seconds than if you do it in 20 seconds

Comment: My only concern with this answer is regarding some dissipative forces. In particular the most obvious one: air.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Pranav. I understand the difference between power and energy. What I wanted to know, and what you answered, is if the total power that needs to be applied will be the same in both cases.

It will be, I think. As you say, energy needed is independent of time. Power required will be greater if you do it in 4 seconds than 20 seconds. But since you only need to apply the power for a shorter time, the total power will be the same. 

As Ignacio points out, some forces like friction and drag will play a part. But assuming those are the same, the energy required is the same.

Comment: I've ignored dissipative forces in my answer. When you say _" Power required will be greater if you do it in 4 seconds than 20 seconds. But since you only need to apply the power for a shorter time, the total power will be the same."_, you are missing out on one important concept: Power multiplied by time gives you energy. So when you say "the total power", you are actually talking about the energy.

Comment: There is no such thing as total power, in much the same way as there is no such thing as the total velocity of a car as it travels from point A to point B. There is the average velocity and the instantaneous velocity.

Comment: I used the phrase "total power" to mean the power applied over time. In other words, the integral of power with respect to time, which as you point out is energy.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to consider. Even if it takes the same energy to accelerate slow vs. fast, if you are ultimately traveling the same distance, then because you got to the faster speed more quickly you will use more energy to cover that distance.

For example.  If you are trying to get to 100kph and you plan to travel a total distance of 1km, you now have 2 cases:
a) In the first case you get to 100kph in 4 seconds, then travel the remaining 1km at 100kph.
b) in the second case you get to 100kph in 20 seconds, then travel the remaining 1km at 100kph

Then in case "a" you will be traveling 100kph for 16 seconds longer than in case "b". Of course if you are in stop & start traffic, and hit that accelerator a lot, then you will experience a significant difference in energy use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as you go from 0 kmph to 100 kmph in either 4 or 20 seconds there is rate of speed/velocity only, we are not talking about rate lf acceleration here. 
Now we can see that in both cases the acceleration would be different; had we been living in an ideal world it wouled not have mattered, but as accelerations are different so would be required forces for said accelerations, these forces even in absense of air would have to overcime friction and therefore heat losses, these lossss would be related to acceleration and hence acheiving same speed in different time would require different energies.

Answer (score -1):

Basic physics.

(1) W = F * s where W is work (energy), F is force and s is distance.
(2) F = m * a where m is mass and a is acceleration.

substitute F in equation (1) with equation (2) and you get (3) W = m * a * s.

From equation (3) assuming  mass and distance are constants, then Work is directly proportional to acceleration. An increase in acceleration means in increase in energy.

Comment: Mass would be constant but distance would not be. A greater acceleration would get the car to the desired speed in a shorter distance. A smaller acceleration would need to be applied over a longer distance to reach the same speed.